# Regexp: How can I clean html tags of attributes but a few in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

Okay, in Notepad++ I want to clean html tags with lots of style attributes, e.g.

```
<td style="width: 457.4pt; border: solid windowtext 1.0pt; background: #BFBFBF; padding: 0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;" colspan="2" valign="top" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
```

and I want this as an outcome:

```
<td colspan="2" valign="top">
```

So far I am at this for search and replace:

```
<([a-z][A-Z]*)[^>]*?>
<$1>
```

which cleans all attributes of a html tag. But I want to keep colspan and valign. How do I have to modify the expression?

Answer (score 1):

This can be error prone, but for the example string you might use a [branch reset group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html) to use 2 capture groups in different order and capture the name of the tag also in a group.

**Find what**

```
<(\w+)[^<>]*(?|(\bcolspan="[^"]*")[^<>]*(\bvalign="[^"]*")|(\bvalign="[^"]*")[^<>]*(\bcolspan="[^"]*"))[^<>]*>
```

**Replace with**

```
<$1 $2 $3>
```

**Explanation**

- `<` Match literally
- `(\w+)` Capture 1+ word chars in group 1
- `[^<>]*` Optionally match any char except `<` and `>` (Assuming no nested tag etc..)
- `(?|` Branch reset group

  - `(\bcolspan="[^"]*")[^<>]*(\bvalign="[^"]*")` Caputure first colspan, then valign
  - `|` Or
  - `(\bvalign="[^"]*")[^<>]*(\bcolspan="[^"]*")` Or capture both the other way around
- `)` Close group
- `[^<>]*` Optionally match any char except `<` and `>`
- `>` Match literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/p4kAF0/1)

[image]

Comment: That works for a single line of code. I have an entire document to clean and not all of them contain colspan or valign. How can I make it match the rest of the document as well?

Comment: @user3231746 The solution is based on what you have stated in your question. It depends on what the document looks like, what you want to match to delete and what you want to keep. If you want to have more control, you might opt for using a dom parser instead of doing this with notepad.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both `colspan` and `valign` are present, maybe:

```
<td([^<>]*?(\h(?:colspan|valign)="\w+"))((?1))[^<>]*>
```

Replace with `<td$2$3>`, see an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/koBAtB/1).

---

[image]